# Creating docker image from VM snapshot

Tags: dockerfile, virtual-machine, amazon-ecs

I was tasked with taking an on prem Windows virtual machine and converting it to a Amazon ecs container. A linux container at that. Is there a way of doing this if I get the snapshot of the VM? Also, would I run into some issues with compatibility since VM snapshots might have some windows artifacts? My plan was to take the vm snapshot, convert that to EC2 and then convert the ec2 ami to ecs. Is that overkill? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Converting a Windows VM to a Linux docker container is impossible. At most you could start from scratch and create a new Windows docker container that has the same software installed as the VM. If you want to have a Linux container you will have to figure out how to install Linux software that does the same thing your current Windows software does.

Comment: "My plan was to take the vm snapshot, convert that to EC2 and then convert the ec2 ami to ecs". Your last step, converting an AMI "to ecs" is not a thing that exists. There is no feature or service in AWS for doing that type of conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark. I am relatively new to ECS and docker so this is great clarity for me.

Comment: ECS task definitions point to a docker image. Correct me if I am wrong but I would have to create a docker image from a dockerfile that contains steps on how to install the software and host it docker hub or some other repository? Then add that repo in the task definition and add the tasks to the ecs cluster I create right?

Comment: Your last comment is exactly right. You have a good grasp of the steps involved. I would only add that you will probably want to upload the image to an AWS ECR (Elastic Container Registry) instead of uploading it to DockerHub.